Does it common for LM (hundreds million parameters) beat LLM (billion parameters) for binary classification task?
Preface
I am trying to fine-tune the transformer-based model (LM and LLM). The LM that I used is DEBERTA, and the LLM is LLaMA 3. The task is to classify whether a text contains condescending language (binary classification).
I use AutoModelForSequenceClassification, which adds a classification layer to the model's top layer for both LM and LLM.
Implementation

Dataset:

Amount: it has about 10.000 texts with each text labeled 0 (for not condescending) and 1 (condescending). The proportion is 1:10 (condescending : not condescending).


Parameter





Parameter
LM
LLM




Batch size
32
16 (per_device_train_batch_size = 4,    gradient_accumulation_steps = 4)


Epoch / steps
2 epoch
1000 steps (20% used as validation set)


Learning Rate
linear (2e-5)
constant (2e-5)


Optimizer
AdamW (lr = 2e-5, eps = 1e-8)
paged_adamw_32bit


Fine-tuning
Full fine-tuning
LoRA (rank=32, dropout=0.5, alpha=8) with 8-bit quantization


Learning Rate
linear (2e-5)
constant (2e-5)


Precision
0,659
0,836


Recall
0,47
0,091


F1-score
0,549
0,164



Question and Issue
Here is the log of the training sample. The validation f1-score is always >0.6. But the validation loss is stuck at 0.24. It is one of the samples of fine-tuned LLM.


Why does the test set f1-score only range from 0 - 0.2 for some parameter variation that I tuned when the f1-score for the validation set is always above 0.6, is it reasonable? why?
Is it common for LM to beat LLM for a particular task? If yes, what is the rationalization?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
